# Interepretation of word2vec evaluation result

Tags: word2vec, evaluation, word-embedding

I have created word embeddings (Word2vec) using my own dataset. I have used Gensim module to create word embeddings. I want to evaluate my word embeddings.

I have used Wordsim353 dataset to evaluate word embeddings. The following code Shows the result of Evaluation.

Code:

```
from gensim.test.utils import datapath

similarities = model.wv.evaluate_word_pairs(datapath('wordsim353.tsv'))

print(similarities)
```

Result:

```
((0.09410256722489568, 0.3086953732794174), SpearmanrResult(correlation=0.06101508426787973, pvalue=0.5097769955392246), 66.28895184135978)
```

How can I interprete the result?

Please help me to interprete the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way we evaluate the quality of word embeddings is to see how closely the similarities computed by embeddings match the actual similarities assigned by human judgements.

Your Pearson and Spearmanr's pValue are too high with approximately 0.3 (70%) and 0.5 (50%). I suggest you should use pretrained word embeddings or collect more dataset.

I have strived to evaluate with glove-twitter-25 and received very great pvalue.

```
import gensim.downloader as api
from gensim.test.utils import datapath

m = api.load("glove-twitter-25")
m.evaluate_word_pairs(datapath("wordsim353.tsv"))
```

output:

```
((0.36409317297819943, pvalue=2.969053896450154e-12), SpearmanrResult(correlation=0.36452011505868487, pvalue=2.788781738485533e-12), 2.26628895184136)
```

[evaluate_word_pairs - Gensim module](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.WordEmbeddingsKeyedVectors.evaluate_word_pairs)

Comment: thank you very much for your help. Can you please suggest how can I calculate accuracy of my embeddings? @Gia Ân Ngô Triệu

Comment: I think you have already calculated your embedding accuracy by evaluate method of Gensim. Your embedding pvalue is 0.3 that mean your accuracy is about 70%. To improve one, you could strive to minimize pvalue. @user11603027

Comment: I have performed Experiments with bigger dataset. I come up with spearman's correlation coefficient = 0.22 with my own dataset. Is it good enough? How can I make comment on such result? Could you please help me to figure it out. @Gia Ân Ngô Triệu